# Is $f$ weakly lower semicontinuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Given a compact subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R}^N$, I wonder if $$f(u)=\int_\Omega (1-|u|^2)^2\ dx$$ is weakly lower semicomtinuous (w.l.s.c) on $H^1(\Omega)$, meaning that if $\lbrace u_n\rbrace$ tends to $u$ weakly, then $f(u)\leq \liminf f(u_n)$. I know that the norm $\Vert u \Vert _{H^1}=   \Vert u \Vert_{L^2} +   \Vert \nabla u \Vert_  {L^2}  $ is w.l.s.c., and so $$\int_\Omega |u|^2\ dx$$ is w.l.s.c.

What can be said about $f$? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I’m proving that $f$ is weakly continuous. I hope that I’m not wrong.

Assume $u_n \rightarrow u$ weakly. By Reillich, $u_n \rightarrow u$ strongly wrt the $L^2$ norm. So we have a subsequence $u_{p_n}$ that converges ae to $u$.

Then by the dominated convergence theorem, $f(u_{p_n}) \rightarrow f(u)$. Since the same statement can be made for any subsequence of $u_n$ instead, it follows that $f$ is continuous wrt the weak topology.

Comment: Which dominating function do you use for DCT?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Im trying now to deal with fatou's lemma. I need to check that $\liminf (1-|u_n|^2)^2 = (1-|u|^2)^2$

Comment: If $H^1$ embeds compactly into L^4 then this works, so $N<4$

Comment: Can you explain that, please?

Comment: @gerw: $1$, since $\Omega$ has finite measure.

Comment: @daw: I actually just need a compact embedding $H^1 \rightarrow L^p$ for some $p>1$, to get the ae convergence of a subsequence of weakly convergent sequence in $H^1$.

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning you did, Mindlack?

Comment: I am showing that for every weakly convergent sequence $u_n$ to $u$ in $H^1$, there is a subsequence $u_{p_n}$ that converges ae, so that $f(u_{p_n})$ converges to $f(u)$ by DCT. So in particular, $f(u)$ is a limit point of any subsequence of $f(u_n)$, which entails $f(u_n) \rightarrow f(u)$ by “standard” real analysis.

Comment: $1$ is not a dominating function. For $u \equiv 3$, you have $(1-u^2)^2 = 64$. For $N \ge 4$, Fatou seems to be the way to go.

Comment: @gerw: right. Stupid me. Fatou it is, then.

Comment: @daw You're right, I made a stupid sign error. I will delete the comment.